# When will onResume() be called without onStart() being called first (Fragment Lifecycle)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

`onStart()` is when the Fragment becomes visible, `onResume()` is when the Fragment becomes interactive. So when will the `onResume()` -> `onPause()` -> `onResume()` cycle execute without executing the encompassing `onStart()` -> `onStop()` cycle?

In terms of `fragment` transitions, a replace will destroy the starting fragment, calling its `onPause()` -> onStop() as well as other destroy related life-cycle methods. If the transition is replace but add the starting `fragment` to `**backStack**`, it will still call `onPause()` -> `onStop()` except without completely destroying the fragment and detaching it from activity. In the case of just overlaying another fragment, none of the starting fragment's `lifecycle` events are executed because its still there just not visible (another fragment getting drawn over it).

I'm not sure when `onResume()` will ever be called without `onStart()`, as well as `onPause()` with `onStop()`.

Edit: Along with the answers already here, using android split screen would also pause the fragment without stopping it.

Comment: I think while using Alert Dialog, when alert dialog is called fragment will go to onPause() and when alert dialog is closed it'll call onResume()

Comment: I believe using split screen would also do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your activity stays visible while showing a dialog or another activity is shown on top that has transparency.

Basically your activity is visible between `onStart()`and `onStop()` and your activity is interactive between `onResume()` and `onPause()`. When it it becomes uninteractive while staying visible you will get onPause without onStop.